# Why does my image stick to bottom of container?

Tags: html, css

When I try to have my "vertical rule" to the right of the image, the image sticks to the bottom of the container.

[image: Play Button]

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:210px;">
        <img src="res/img/PlayBtn.png" style="top:-100px; padding:5px;">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:12px;">
        <div style="height:450px; width:0px; border:1px solid #000; margin:5px; margin-top:0px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this, while keeping the image at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default positioning for `inline-block` elements is `baseline`. Set: `vertical-align:top` on your divs

```
<div>
   <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; width:210px;">
      <img src="res/img/PlayBtn.png" style="top:-100px; padding:5px;">
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; width:12px;">
      <div style="height:450px; width:0px; border:1px solid #000; margin:5px; margin-top:0px;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using floats to put things side-by-side, but for a quick solution, just add `vertical-align:top` to the button div:

```
...
<div style="display:inline-block; width:210px; vertical-align: top;">
    <img src="res/img/PlayBtn.png" style="top:-100px; padding:5px;">
</div>
...
```